# Windows Explorer Context Menu click function is not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, contextmenu

I want to let the users to select only the following extension files: `.jpg,.png, .tiff, .gif, .png`. using `Windows Explorer Context Menu`  I followed this link:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15171/Simple-shell-context-menu?msg=4779433#xx4779433xx and I could register and un-register successfully for .jpg file.

When I click on the command `fileCopytoDirA`nothing is happening i.e the function is not working. (I followed the same approach using console application with my function it works).

Where & How should i call the function during the '`fileCopytoDirA` click?? Any help?

![enter image description here][1]

Code to register in the registry:

```
InitializeComponent();
string menuCommand = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"%L\"", Application.Current);
FileShellExtension.Register("OISjpegfile", "fileCopytoDirA", "fileCopytoDirA", menuCommand);
```

Function to be executed during click:

```
 static void fileCopytoDirA(string filePath)
     { 
        try
            {          
                File.Copy(filePath, System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\Test\Directories\", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath)), true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("An error occurred: {0}", ex.Message));
                return;
            }
       }

Function to un register the registry entries during WPF application close:

     private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
            {

                FileShellExtension.Unregister("OISjpegfile", "fileCopytoDirA");
            }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAN5F.png
```

Edit after`Metadings`answer:

```
 App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string menuCommand = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"%L\"", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            FileShellExtension.Register("OISjpegfile", "fileCopytoDirA", "fileCopytoDirA", menuCommand);
        }

        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string args)
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(args))
            {
                // Run your Main Form
                // (blocks until Form1 is closed)
                Window3 window = new Window3();
                App app = new App();
                app.Run(window);
            }
            else
            {
                // Run the context menu action
                fileCopytoDirA(args);
            }

            // exit
        }

        static void fileCopytoDirA(string args)
        {
            try
            {

                File.Copy(args, System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\Test\Directories\", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(args)), true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("An error occurred: {0}", ex.Message));
                return;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The (simple) registry setting is that your application is executed by arguments, as it would be called in a console:

```
app.exe "TheJpegFile.jpg"
```

So the entry point is `static void Main(string args)`, from there you can call `fileCopytoDirA(args)`. There is no magic way Explorer calls a function by its name. You can either [implement the COM interfaces, as for example this project does](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/174369/How-to-Write-Windows-Shell-Extension-with-NET-Lang), or you go the quick and dirty way, by redirecting your Main; if there is not an argument, run the (windows forms) application - if there is an argument, do the action and exit:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public static class Program {

    public static void Main(string args) {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(args)) {
            // Run your Main Form
            // (blocks until Form1 is closed)
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
        else {
            // Run the context menu action
            fileCopytoDirA(args);
        }

        // exit
    }

}
```

The FileShellExtension.Register function is defined as

```
public static void Register(string fileType,
       string shellKeyName, string menuText, string menuCommand)
```

So the arguments are

1. `string fileType` - the HKC registry key for the file extension
2. `string shellKeyName` - just a registry key name for Explorer to distinguish shell extensions
3. `string menuText` - what the user can see in Explorer's context menu
4. `string menuCommand` - the shell command Explorer executes just like you can do in a console or by a link

---

P.S: In WPF it's similar, but you create new YourApp class (derived from System.Windows.Application) and then call Run.

Assuming Application.xaml looks like

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    StartupUri="Window1.xaml">
</Application>
```

and your application class is in namespace `WpfApplication1` named `App`, and you have a Window1.xaml, the q'n'd looks like

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string args)
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(args)) {
                // Run your Main Form
                // (blocks until Form1 is closed)
                Window1 window = new Window1();
                App app = new App();
                app.Run(window);
            }
            else {
                // Run the context menu action
                fileCopytoDirA(args);
            }

            // exit
        }

        static void fileCopytoDirA(string args) {
            // this your part ;)
        }
    }
}
```

Btw. I took the WPF Main part from [this source](http://ludovic.chabant.com/devblog/2010/04/20/writing-a-custom-main-method-for-wpf-applications/) and it seems to be important that you remove the `StartupURI="Window1.xaml"` attribute from your Application.xaml, that it looks now like

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
</Application>
```

Comment: Thank you & i followed your approach..still it didn't in WPF. I made the  `FileShellExtension.Register` directlt in the app.xaml.cs but when i click on it, it open another window of the wpf and the image is not transferred to the defined dir. Please see the question, I have updated what i did from your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Most likely because a WPF project creates an own void Main method, as you may see in `~/obj/Debug/App.g.cs`; the article where I took the info from also states: "You basically need to change the application’s build action from 'Application Definition' to 'Page'.